# Adding Attribute to Root Element of Output

Tags: xml, xslt

So I need to add 4 attributes to the root element (<weather>) of an XML output I am creating using XSLT. The 4 elements are the details of the weather station the data is obtained from. Which is contained within the stations.xml file and has a structure as follows:

```
<stations>
   <station>
       <site>81123</site>
       <name>Bendigo Airport</name>
       <latitude>36.74</latitude>
       <longitude>144.33</longitude>
       <state>Vic</state>
   </station>
   <station>
       <site>81124</site>
       <name>Yarrawonga</name>
       <latitude>36.03</latitude>
       <longitude>146.03</longitude>
       <state>Vic</state>
   </station>
</stations>
```

An XPath tester tells me that the following would be the correct predicate to obtain the required station node.

```
./stations/station[site=81123]
```

I've tried to do it by matching but I think I've lost my way here. If anyone can offer some assistance that would be great. The code I have so far is below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- select the <measurement> elements of all the various input files -->
<xsl:variable name="maxTemp" select="document('Max_temp.xml')/*" />
<xsl:variable name="rainfall" select="document('Rainfall.xml')/*" />
<xsl:variable name="solar" select="document('Solar.xml')/*" />
<xsl:variable name="minTemp" select="document('Min_temp.xml')/*" />
<xsl:variable name="stations" select="document('station.xml')/*" />

<!-- index <measurement> elements by their station and date -->
<xsl:key name="kMeasurement" match="measurement"
    use="concat(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year)"
/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <weather>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="weather" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$maxTemp/measurement" />
    </weather>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="weather">
    <xsl:attribute name="stationID"><xsl:value-of select="$stations/station[site=81123]/site" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="stationName"><xsl:value-of select="$stations/station[site=81123]/name" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="latitude"><xsl:value-of select="$stations/station[site=81123]/latitude" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="longitude"><xsl:value-of select="$stations/station[site=81123]/longitude" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="measurement">
    <xsl:variable name="currentKey" select="concat(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year)" />

    <measurement>
        <Date><xsl:value-of select="concat(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year)" /></Date>

        <!-- since we are handling maxTemp measurements here, we can output that directly -->
        <MaxTemp><xsl:value-of select="MaxTemp"/></MaxTemp>

        <!-- to access the others we need a context switch and a key lookup -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$rainfall">
            <Rainfall><xsl:value-of select="key('kMeasurement', $currentKey)/Volume" /></Rainfall>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$solar">
            <Solar><xsl:value-of select="key('kMeasurement', $currentKey)/dailySolarExposure" /></Solar>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="$minTemp">
            <MinTemp><xsl:value-of select="key('kMeasurement', $currentKey)/minTemp" /></MinTemp>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </measurement>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the example to the problem at hand, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="stations" select="document('station.xml')/*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <weather>
        <xsl:variable name="station" select="$stations/station[site=81123]" />
        <xsl:attribute name="stationID"><xsl:value-of select="$station/site" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="stationName"><xsl:value-of select="$station/name" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="latitude"><xsl:value-of select="$station/latitude" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="longitude"><xsl:value-of select="$station/longitude" /></xsl:attribute>

        <!-- create content here -->

    </weather>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weather stationID="81123" stationName="Bendigo Airport" latitude="36.74" longitude="144.33"/>
```

provided it's run against a valid XML input and that the document named `station.xml` is in the same directory where the stylesheet is located.

---

If you prefer, you can shorten the above code to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="stations" select="document('station.xml')/*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="station" select="$stations/station[site=81123]" />
    <weather stationID="{$station/site}" stationName="{$station/name}" latitude="{$station/latitude}" longitude="{$station/longitude}">

        <!-- create content here -->

    </weather>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The data inputs are returning nulls by the look of things.

Comment: @RoryPerry I am afraid I don't understand your description of the problem. Make sure you are running this against some valid XML input, and that the `station.xml` document is in the same directory where the stylesheet is located.

Comment: XML Files are all valid. All in the same directory. Output is: <weather stationID="" stationName="" latitude="" longitude="">

Comment: Nevermind, I attribute all of this to a rather simple spelling mistake. Should of been stations.xml My apologies if I caused any confusion!